# Make the post's comments toggleable in Rails using Jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

Scenario：A post has many comments. In the index page of posts, when user clicks the show link( link_to post), its comments will show below the post.

Here I use the append() to add the comments:
`$('#edit_post_<%= @post.id %>').append('<%= j render "comments/comments" %>')`So when user click the show link, comments would be load and show up.

But how can I hide these comments again (i.e to make comments toggeable) ?

posts/index

```
<h1>Posts</h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= form_for post, remote: true do |f| %>
        <%=  post.content %>
        <div id="post_<%= post.id %>">
          <%= link_to "show", post, remote: true  %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

posts/show.js.erb

```
$('#edit_post_<%= @post.id %>').append('<%= j render "comments/comments" %>')
```

comments/_comments.html.erb

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.content %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you dont have the event bindings for new comments.

you should use something like

```
$('.container-of-your-comments').on('click', '.the-toggle-button', function (e) {
  // toggle
});
```

so toggling works for all (also future) elements.

**EDIT:**

given the changes in the question: if toggle means just hiding the whole comment list,
you have to do it manually.

i suggest you have separate show / hide buttons (you can show and hide the buttons upon changing state as well), because if not, it gets more complex.

so for example, in posts/index:

```
<h1>Posts</h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= form_for post, remote: true do |f| %>
        <%=  post.content %>
        <div id="post_<%= post.id %>">
          <%= link_to "show", post, remote: true %>
        </div>

        <div class="post-comments" id="post_comments_<%= post.id %>">
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

in comments/_comments.html.erb

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.content %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "hide", '#', class: "hide-comments"  %>
```

and in posts/show.js.erb

```
$('#post_comments<%= @post.id %>').html('<%= j render "comments/comments" %>')
```

and in assets/javascripts/posts.js (be sure you include this in your application.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hide-comments').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().hide();
    });
});
```

backbone.js is a great tool, if you'll be doing a lot of things with those comments, like CRUD etc. and you need to stay on one page - use backbone.js. if not, stick to jQuery.

Comment: So, besides using a link to append the comments, I also have to add a toggel button to hide these comments?

Comment: can you paste the code?  hard to tell without actually seeing.

Comment: Just updated. I hope that'll help. Thank you. But after wandering about, I think I may have used the wrong tool? It seems like that this feature should rely on things like Backbone.js and Angular.js?

Comment: And you can see the code here that when you click the "show", you actually load the comments from the server. And that's why I'm considering adding another button to allow user tohide these comments again.